# Concatenate videos and add black frames between them with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have three videos that I am concatenating with ffmpeg. I would like to add a few black frames in between them. Although I've found a few hints on the web it has not worked for me yet. I have tried to generate an 'empty' video with just black frames with:

```
ffmpeg -t 20 -s 1920x1080 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i c:\nul  E:\empty.avi
```

and then concatenate with another one but doesn't work. I have tried a few other things without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: also tried to add black frames before and after video with the following code, but no success:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=25:d=100 -i middle_video.avi -filter_complex 
"[0:v]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=21[blackstart];
[0:v] trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=21 [blackend]; 
[blackstart] [1:v] [blackend] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" -c:v qtrle -c:a -copy output.avi
```

EDIT2:
Output from ffprobe

```
Metadata:
encoder: Lavf57.3.100
Duration: 00:00:10.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 43302 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 192
0x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 43333 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 10k tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 k
b/s
```

EDIT 3
Link to the report of the ffmpeg console output:
[FFMPEG session report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pij6fvcp2c1h45f/ffmpeg-20160425-134857.log?dl=0)

Comment: Paste the readout of `ffprobe` for the the three input files. That will reveal the properties the blank video needs to have.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that.  it tells me: 'Output file is empty, nothing was encoded'

Comment: Paste the ffprobe output into the Q.

Comment: Done and paste it in the EDIT2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**#1** Generate your blank video

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1920x1080:r=24000/1001 -f lavfi -i anullsrc \
       -ar 48000 -ac 2 -t 20 empty.avi
```

**#2** Prepare a text file with list of files

```
file '1.avi'
file 'empty.avi'
duration 1
file '2.avi'
file 'empty.avi'
duration 1
file '3.avi'
```

**#3** Concat

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:v qtrle -c:a copy joined.avi
```

---

The above assumes that all 3 videos have the same properties as shown in the ffprobe readout. You can control the duration of the blank segment using the duration argument in the textfile (currently 1 second). Only upto the duration of empty.avi, of course.

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work. I've got an empty video, although the soundtrack seems to be right. A list of that kind of errors appeared in the prompt:[avi @ 0000000000434440] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 4340
, current: 2755; changing to 4341. This may result in incorrect timestamps in th
e output file.

Comment: Paste the entire console readout of the concat command into your Q.

Comment: Too long so added a link to the report in my Q on Edit 3

Comment: a)Does `ffplay joined.avi` also show a blank video? If yes, run `ffmpeg -i joined.avi -c copy joined.mov` and play that using ffplay.

Comment: Impossible to play it with ffplay, it is listing errors: [rawvideo @ 0000000000567020] Invalid buffer size, packet size 1869586 < expected frame_size 6220800

Comment: Ok, tested it here. Your concat should output to `joined.mov`.AVI uses VfW decoders and they apparently don't understand QTRLE.

Comment: That solved it and now videos are joined with black frames in between! Thank yous so much!

Comment: So the answer is incorrect and correct answer should be searched in comments.